# Invalid preprocessing directive for #elseifdef in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Why:

```
 #ifdef SOME_TARGET_FLAG     
      <some code here>
    #elseifdef SOME_ANOTHER_TARGET_FLAG
      <some another code here>
    #endif
```

produces **"Invalid preprocessing directive" preprocess compilation error?**

SOME_TARGET_FLAG and SOME_ANOTHER_TARGET_FLAG are just some "Other C-flags" defined in target build settings (`-D<FLAG_NAME>` pattern).

Is **#elseifdef** directive not supported by Xcode?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Is #elseifdef directive not supported by Xcode?

It is not. Use this instead:

```
#elif defined(SOME_ANOTHER_TARGET_FLAG)
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not supported as indicated by the error message. See 'the C preprocessor' - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/gcc-4.2.1/cpp/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007092  (conditional compilation).